# What happend internally in the case of null and undefined comparision?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

```
console.log(null == undefined); // prints true
console.log(null === undefined); // prints false
```

The second statement is clear to me, no type conversion takes place and therefore false is printed.
But what happens in the first statement, what is converted to what? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: There's an explicit clause in the language spec for `==` comparison of `null` and `undefined`. There is no type conversion; it's a special case for those two particular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "conversion" is going on. They just compare equal, similar to the distinct values `+0` and `-0`.